# How to implement Vertical dotted line below image in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout, ui-design

How can I achieve this kind of layout without using any library??

[image]

I tried something like this but was unable to get the exact layout

**my_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_tick"
                android:layout_width="17dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tick" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/iv_tick"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_tick"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
                android:text="This is my text. This is my text. This is my text. This is my text. "
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/dotted_line"
                android:foregroundGravity="left"
                android:layout_below="@+id/iv_tick"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <!--<com.example.myapplication.DividerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:color="#ff0000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:dashLength="5dp"
            android:dashGap="1dp"
            android:dashThickness="1dp" />-->
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**dotted_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ff0000"
            android:dashWidth="4dp"
            android:dashGap="4dp" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

This is the result I get with the above implemented code. How to get the result something like the image I have posted above?

I even tried constraint layout but no help with that too.

[image]

Comment: How about using [StepView](https://github.com/shuhart/StepView) or [VerticalStepperForm](https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/VerticalStepperForm)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/14581602/7666442

Comment: This may helps you, `SO` link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936373/how-to-create-android-timeline-view-like-google-location-history and other library link https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output:

[image: Check preview]

Use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_5"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@color/grey_10" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:tint="#9CCC65"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_round_solid" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Taylor W "
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                                android:textColor="#000"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@color/grey_10" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:tint="#29B6F6"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_round_solid" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Taylor W "
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                                android:textColor="#000"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@color/grey_10" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:tint="#FF4081"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_round_solid" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Taylor W "
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                                android:textColor="#000"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_smlarge"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@color/grey_10" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:tint="#F57F17"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_round_solid" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Taylor W "
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                                android:textColor="#000"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Create a drawable in drawable folder name `drawable/shape_round_solid`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp" />

</shape>
```

Add this `dimens.xml`

```
<!--genaral spacing-->
<dimen name="spacing_xsmall">2dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_small">3dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_medium">5dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xmedium">7dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_middle">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_large">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_smlarge">18dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_mlarge">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_mxlarge">25dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xlarge">35dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xmlarge">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xxlarge">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_xxxlarge">55dp</dimen>
<dimen name="appbar_padding_top">8dp</dimen>
```

Hope that this will works for all.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create the file "/res/values/attrs.xml" with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="DividerView">
    <attr name="color" format="color" />
    <attr name="dashLength" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="dashGap" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="dashThickness" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="orientation" format="enum">
        <enum name="horizontal" value="0" />
        <enum name="vertical" value="1" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

2.Create the class DividerView with the below contents:

```
public class DividerView extends View {
static public int ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL = 0;
static public int ORIENTATION_VERTICAL = 1;
private Paint mPaint;
private int orientation;

public DividerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    int dashGap, dashLength, dashThickness;
    int color;

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DividerView, 0, 0);

    try {
        dashGap = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DividerView_dashGap, 5);
        dashLength = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DividerView_dashLength, 5);
        dashThickness = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.DividerView_dashThickness, 3);
        color = a.getColor(R.styleable.DividerView_color, 0xff000000);
        orientation = a.getInt(R.styleable.DividerView_orientation, ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(dashThickness);
    mPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { dashLength, dashGap, }, 0));
}

public DividerView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (orientation == ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL) {
        float center = getHeight() * .5f; 
        canvas.drawLine(0, center, getWidth(), center, mPaint);
    } else {
        float center = getWidth() * .5f; 
        canvas.drawLine(center, 0, center, getHeight(), mPaint);
    }
}
}
```

Xml code like this:-

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_tick"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello This Is My Text" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.example.YOURPACKAGENAME.DividerView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layerType="software"
    custom:color="#ff0000"
    custom:dashGap="2dp"
    custom:dashLength="6dp"
    custom:dashThickness="2dp"
    custom:orientation="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello This Is My Text" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.example.YOURPACKAGENAME.DividerView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layerType="software"
    custom:color="#ff0000"
    custom:dashGap="2dp"
    custom:dashLength="6dp"
    custom:dashThickness="2dp"
    custom:orientation="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello This Is My Text" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.example.YOURPACKAGENAME.DividerView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layerType="software"
    custom:color="#ff0000"
    custom:dashGap="2dp"
    custom:dashLength="6dp"
    custom:dashThickness="2dp"
    custom:orientation="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello This Is My Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Screen Shot

[image: Screen Shot]

I hope that can help you!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to implement dotted line.

Horizontal and vertical dotted lines in android using shapes.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90" >

    <shape android:shape="line" >
        <stroke
            android:dashGap="6px"
            android:dashWidth="6px"
            android:color="#C7B299" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

(OR)

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:drawable="@drawable/horizontal_line"/>
```